# Android chrisjenx/Calligraphy Custom font defined in Theme using Theme.AppCompat not working

Tags: android, textview, android-styles, custom-font

I want to use chrisjenx/Calligraphy in Theme to change the font in my Whole project.

I followed the instructions but it's not working for me

here's my code:

in application :

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(base));
}



 @Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                            .setDefaultFontPath("BElham.ttf")
                            .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                            .build()
            );
}
```

here's my style

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/AppTheme.Widget.TextView</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Widget"/>

<style name="AppTheme.Widget.TextView" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="fontPath">BElham.ttf</item>
</style>
```

Comment: http://mobikul.com/android-calligraphy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write following code to each activity and not in Application class.
Better put this in BaseActivity and extend it in all other Activities

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(base));
}
```

I am able to use your code and implement at my end.

Answer (score 1):

try this first create an application class

MyApplication.java

```
 @Override
public void onCreate() {
TypefaceUtil.overrideFont(getApplicationContext(), "SERIF", "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf"); // font from assets: "assets/fonts/chrisjenx.ttf
}
```

Then create a class
TypefaceUtil.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class TypefaceUtil {


public static void overrideFont(Context context,
        String defaultFontNameToOverride, String customFontFileNameInAssets) {
    try {
        final Typeface customFontTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(
                context.getAssets(), customFontFileNameInAssets);

        final Field defaultFontTypefaceField = Typeface.class
                .getDeclaredField(defaultFontNameToOverride);
        defaultFontTypefaceField.setAccessible(true);
        defaultFontTypefaceField.set(null, customFontTypeface);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Can not set custom font "
                + customFontFileNameInAssets + " instead of "
                + defaultFontNameToOverride);
    }
    }
 }
```

In your style.xml inside your theme add for e.g

```
 <style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base"parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

     <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>

</style>
```

Thats it

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a folder named "fonts" in asset folder and put the fonts in them
your font path should be like this `assets/fonts/BElham.ttf`
and then define the fonts like that

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();
CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                        .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/BElham.ttf")
                        .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                        .build()
        );
}
```

Comment: have u changed your fontpath? `.setDefaultFontPath("fonts/BElham.ttf")`